# Google Cloud Print with Zebra printer

Tags: google-cloud-print

We are trying to print a PDF file on a Zebra thermo printer via Google Cloud Print. The printer is connected to GCP via the Windows Chrome Browser GCP proxy on Windows 10.

NB: Chrome can only print the PDF correctly on this printer when using System Print Dialog. Printing with the Chrome dialog causes the same effect.

Printing works, but the image is scaled into the wrong dimensions.

We use the following CJT:

```
   {
    "version":"1.0",
    "print":{
            "copies":{
                    "copies":1
                    },
            "page_orientation":{
                "type":0
                },
            "margins": {
                "top_microns":0,
                "bottom_microns":0,
                "left_microns":0,
                "right_microns":0
                },
            "fit_to_page": {
                "type": "NO_FITTING"
                },
            "dpi": {
                "horizontal_dpi":203,
                "vertical_dpi":203
                },
            "media_size": {
                    "width_microns": 100000,
                    "height_microns": 37000,
                    "is_continuous_feed": True
                    }
            }
    }
```

The PDF has a mediaBox, trimBox, bleedBox, artBox set to [0, 0, 238.46460, 108.88190]. The printers page properties are set 10cm width, 3.7cm height.

With this settings, only the center part of the label is printed (and the part is scaled too small).

We also tried different `fit_to_page` settings.

PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1m2K70eVXaXZF9raG5OakthZnc/view?usp=sharing

Printout: https://goo.gl/photos/J74VFS1coMDteSpm8

Comment: Since the output is the same from Chrome and via the Cloud Print proxy built in to Chrome, but correct via the system print dialog, I think it's safe to assume that you're looking at a Chrome bug, not a Cloud Print bug. I suggest you write a clear bug to this effect, with lots of emphasis on the Chrome part, at crbug.com.

It would also help if you tried to print from Chrome on OSX or Linux.

Comment: I have the same problem. And Google Cloud Print API is really a pain to work with. The documentation level is close to 0. And when changing the parameters, it doesn't seem to apply correctly.